# Prove that $(a^2-bc)^3+(b^2-ac)^3+(c^2-ab)^3=3(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)(c^2-ab)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a+b+c=0$. Prove that 
>   $$(a^2-bc)^3+(b^2-ac)^3+(c^2-ab)^3=3(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)(c^2-ab)$$

**My work so far:**

I used the formula
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$$
Then $$(a^2-bc)^3+(b^2-ac)^3+(c^2-ab)^3-3(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)(c^2-ab)=$$
$$=(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\times$$
$$\times\left((a^2-bc)^2+(b^2-ac)^2+(c^2-ab)^2-(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)-(b^2-ac)(c^2-ab)-(a^2-bc)(c^2-ab) \right)$$

But if $a\not=b$ or $a\not=b$ or $a\not=c$ then $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca>0$.

**How do I prove** 
$$(a^2-bc)^2+(b^2-ac)^2+(c^2-ab)^2-(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)-(b^2-ac)(c^2-ab)-(a^2-bc)(c^2-ab)=0?$$

Comment: Expand both sides: $L.H.S.=x$, $R.H.S.=y$ and if $x=y$ you can conclude by the transitivity of equality that since $L.H.S.=x=y=R.H.S.$, then $L.H.S.=R.H.S.$

Comment: There is  a mixture of cubes and squares on the left!?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think it should they should be all cubes

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thank you! I edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a^2-bc=x$, $b^2-ca=y$, $c^2-ab=z$. Then note $$x-y=a^2-bc+ca-b^2=(a-b)(a+b+c)=0$$$$y-z=b^2-ca+ab-c^2=(b-c)(a+b+c)=0$$Thus we have $x=y=z$. We are done.